# C# can't get the correct subnetmask

Tags: c#, subnet, system-information

I am making a program that among other things collects system information. However I am having some problems obtaining the subnet mask. I am new to programming so this is probably related to my lack of skills.
My code looks like this:

```
public string Subnet()
{
     string Maske = "";
     foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
     if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
     {
         IPInterfaceProperties ipInterface = f.GetIPProperties();
         foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation unicastAddress in ipInterface.UnicastAddresses)
         {
             Maske = unicastAddress.IPv4Mask.ToString();
         }
     }
     return Maske;
}
```

I only get 255.0.0.0 as a result. I have disabled or uninstalled the other network cards but I still get this result.

Comment: What's the expected subnet mask? In most cases (home network) it's 255.255.255.0, but it's possible that your network is configured to use 255.0.0.0. (To validate you can cmd.exe -> ipconfig)

Comment: The expected one is: 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that there may be more than one entry in in ipInterface.UnicastAddresses or NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()? Your method only takes the last one found. I tested your method on my pc, and the list contained three entries: 255.255.255.0, 0.0.0.0 and  255.0.0.0...

EDIT: You may need to ignore network interfaces with the NetworkInterfaceType Loopback, as there are sometimes some virtual software interfaces installed...

```
if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && f.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
```

Comment: Yes, or at least i expected it would. Thats why I have tried to disable the other cards. Is there a way to only get info from the one card that are in use? There is no need for multiple cards information.
Shouldn't the "OperationalStatus.Up" filter out the once that are not in use?